# Preventing write permissions on specific devices

Tags: usb, permissions, external-hard-drive, cloud-storage

On my quest to go full cloud-storage-free, I moved all my files from my cloud service into a portable HD and I purchased a USB to smartphone (OTG) cable so that I can connect my HD to my phone when needed.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected, as I have already encountered a few corrupt files here and there (specifically when moving photos from my phone's memory into my HD), even though I have been **very careful** about unmounting my HD from my phone before unplugging.

While it's not the best solution, from now on, I plan to use this HD with my phone but only to browse and open files – not write.

My question is this: While a portable HD is mounted on a phone (or computer) and given that I freely browse and open files but never modify any of them (or move any files from/into the HD), is there anything else that's being written on the HD? Maybe probably on the background, without me even knowing?

a. If no, would this new way of using it be enough so that I don't encounter other corrupt files in the future?

b. If yes, how can I prevent any write process on the HD? Could I set an HD to recognize a device and automatically disable write permissions?

c. Would replacing my portable HD with an SSD, or a flash drive, or an SD card, by any chance make things easier for me or enable me to set different permissions?

I'm on a MacBook and an Android phone most of the time, if it makes any difference. But the idea is to be able to use it with any device.

I know I can't be the only one who's wished to go full cloud-free, but I've found so many obstacles on my quest to do it, it's unbelievable.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things might be being written.  The most likely is file access times, but there are others (for example, checking a filesystem as done after an unexpected power loss will usually write to it).

Now, as to file corruption, there are three probable sources:

1. USB itself.  USB is horrible for storage devices, period.  It's unreliable, has poor performance (even with UAS support and USB 3.1), and has absolutely atrocious error recovery.  It is used for this type of thing simply because it's easy, and for most people that trumps reliability.  If you can find some way to avoid using USB, you will immediately make things more reliable (eSATA is pretty good for what it's worth, and Thunderbolt is great as an alternative).  Note that most of this is either a result of power issues (a lot of USB hard drives need more power than one USB port can provide, hence the weird Y shaped cables some come with), or odd USB host controllers (the USB controllers found in most computers have very few issues most of the time as long as the mechanical connection between the cable and port is solid, but a lot of mobile USB controllers have odd edges cases where they don't work right).
2. The circuitry to control the disk.  There is no such thing as a USB hard drive, all of them are SATA or IDE hard drives connected to a USB-to-SATA or USB-to-IDE adapter, and such adapters are notoriously problematic as well, although some brands are better than others (ASMedia seems to make really good chipsets for these, but of course it's hard to find out what chipset one is using without buying it yourself).
3. Actual media problems.  If it's a regular hard drive, you have to deal with any issues caused by rough handling.  If it's an SSD (or flash drive), you have to deal with poor data retention (flash memory is not good at long-term data retention, in fact it's far worse than traditional magnetic media at it).  Unless you're being really rough with the disk, this shouldn't be an issue this fast, but do keep in mind that just dropping a traditional hard drive can be enough to cause data corruption.

Pretty much, the moment you require the ability to use it with anything, you paint yourself into a corner that makes it inevitable to have to deal with data corruption inherent to the setup itself (not the devices you connect to).  Even if you restrict it to just Mac and Android, you're not going to have a very easy time finding a good option for long-term storage that isn't cloud storage.

Personally, I would go with optical media for this (Blu-Ray probably, you get 50 or 100GB of data per disk that way), as it's almost the gold standard for archival data storage (tapes still beat out optical media believe it or not in terms of both data density and sheer amount of use).  While you still would have to use USB, USB optical drives tend to be much more reliable than USB hard drives.

Aside from all that though, had you considered looking at cloud storage services that are targeted towards businesses instead of consumers?  I'm not particularly fond of most of the consumer options (OneDrive, Dropbox, Google Drive, etc) myself for various reasons, but I've had very good results with Amazon S3.  Initial setup can be a bit daunting, and it's not exactly something you can access like a filesystem, but with S3 you can pretty easily get to your files from anything with a web browser (you just log into your account and download the files), and the pricing isn't too bad at a few cents a month for data you're not accessing frequently (I'm paying about 5  USD a month for about 50GB of data stored with two copies of each item).

Comment: Hi and thank you for the time you spent to write an extensive answer to help me. Also, sorry for the back to back responses, but apparently I'm not allowed to post too many characters per comment.

→ 1. I wish I could move to eSATA, but unfortunately most devices don't support it by default, and I'm guessing (please correct me if I'm wrong) that using it through an eSATA to USB (or Thunderbolt) port eliminates its purpose as you still rely, well, on USB...

I'm not in any way defending USB, but I've used it for so many years with no problems, and my experience with it hasn't been too bad.

Comment: I always thought that being careful about unmounting would grant a smooth transition of data, and I don't really recall any corrupt files experience in the past – I mean up until now with my phone.

→ 3. In response to “rough handling”: it is a regular portable HD but I'm extra careful with my devices in general.

Blu-Ray wouldn't really cut it, I'd have to carry around an external Blu-Ray drive.

If I limited “work with any device” to “Mac and Android phone”, can you think of any workaround?

Comment: I actually tried formatting the disk to HFS+ hopefully expecting that my phone would read but not write to it, but it doesn't even read it and when I install plugins to fix that they all provide read and write. And I clearly don't trust my phone writing anything to my HD at this point.

I'm suspecting I might be forced to move back to cloud storage, which I literally despise, when its being used for anything other than exchange of files between friends and colleagues.

Comment: @J.Do. I've updated my answer with some further clarification based on your questions here in the comments.

Comment: I'll try some of the solutions you suggested and we'll see. Again, thank you very much for your response.